# How to pass an audio file in asset through dataItem from mobile app to android wear app

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I want to pass an **audio file** from the **mobile app** to the wear app. From android developer guidelines I know it can be done through assests. But I need a sample code on how the file with **.amr extension** could be added in the asset and passed.

Comment: Have you looked at the official docs, like http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html? There is enough material  to get you going.

Comment: I looked into that link already, it has an example for passing image only through asset.

Comment: That page shows how to build an asset by calling Asset.createFromBytes(byte[]), so it doesn't care if it is an image or something else; you need to learn how to do I/O in java to read a file into bytes; you can't expect to find an example that exactly uses an *.amr file!